# Question of ultrafilters/prime ideals in finite Boolean algebras

Tags: boolean-algebra, filters, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $U$ be an ultrafilter in a **finite** Boolean algebra $A$. Does $U$ **necessarily** contains an atom of $A$?

Let $I$ be a prime ideal in the same finite Boolean algebra $A$. Does $I$ **necessarily** contains the complement of an atom of $A$?

If these two statements are correct. Does this mean that there are as many ultrafilters (prime ideals) in a finite Boolean algebra as there are atoms (complements of atoms)?

Comment: hint: every ultrafilter in a finite set is principal

Answer (score 2):

Every ultrafilter on a finite Boolean algebra is fixed (principal) and therefore contains an atom; there is exactly one ultrafilter for each atom. The ultrafilters on a Boolean algebra are precisely the prime filters, so the prime ideals are the complements of the ultrafilters. Thus, both statements are correct.

Comment: Thank you very much. I suppose this is why ultrafilters are considered as a generalisation of atoms.

Comment: @student: You’re very welcome.